# Color font editor Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

The font of the editing part (i.e., left part) in Texmaker is grey. Therefore, it is not that easy to use when you spend several hours on Textmaker.

Do you know how one can change the font color to black (as in any Word document, for example)?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sure it is grey? The screenshots on https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/shots.html suggest that the text is black.

Comment: Hi Marijn, thank you for your reply. Yes, oddly it is grey... (I just downloaded it today since I changed my computer)

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the newest version and it looks good to me (Win 10).

[image]